# How to insert a dynamic sql variable into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, stored-procedures, varchar

So I want to insert the variables email, username, and age from a stored procedure into a temporary table and am running into a few issues.

```sql
Declare @email [varchar](8000)
,@user_name [varchar](8000)
, age[int]
```

```sql
select distinct value as value
into #temptable
from @email
,@user_name
,@age


select *
from #temptable
```

I am getting a syntax error. Does anybody have any advice?

Comment: Even with that there is a syntax error

Comment: It looks like you are using Microsoft SQL Server syntax, but you tagged your question [tag:mysql]. Which database brand are you really using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would use this syntax to insert the results of a stored procedure into a table or table variable:

```
INSERT #temptable EXECUTE dbo.MyStoredProcedureName
```

For example (table variable example):

```
declare @temptable table
(
    name varchar(255),
    field varchar(255),
    filename varchar(255),
    filegroup varchar(255),
    size varchar(255),
    maxsize varchar(255),
    growth varchar(255),
    usage varchar(255)
);

INSERT @temptable Exec sp_helpfile;
select * from @temptable ;
```

EDIT: Per your question about why can't you do this in the SP itself, the syntax would be something like:

```
DECLARE @Email nvarchar(4000),@UserName nvarchar(4000),@age int
declare @temptable table
(
    email nvarchar(4000),
    UserName nvarchar(4000),
    age int
)

SELECT  @Email = 'test@test.com', @UserName = 'MyName', @age = 21

INSERT INTO @temptable(Email, UserName, age) SELECT @Email, @UserName, @age

SELECT * FROM @temptable
```

Comment: Well the thing is the stored procedure is supposed to insert the data into the table. Why is why is it that you execute another stored procedure to do that? I'm a little bit confused

Comment: Sorry, I may not be clearly understanding your needs. Edited the response to try to help.